# Question about forwarding errors from Promise.All to external try … catch

Tags: promise, try-catch

Code:

```
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   reject("error promise1");
});
const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 resolve('test promice2')
});

try {
  Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
   .then(values => {
     const [promise1data, promise2data] = values;
     console.log(promise1data, promise2data); 
   })
   .catch(error => {
    //console.log('error email', error)
    throw `ERROR catch1! ${error}`;
   });

} catch (err) {
  console.log('ERROR catch2', err)
}
```

Expecting the console output ERROR catch2 and error promise1, but I get:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning
DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise
rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Don't mix `async/await` with `.then().catch()`. They are syntactic alternatives and don't make particuarly good bed-fellows. Although the language allows them to be mixed, it's not good practice (within the same function). The code becomes difficult to follow.

Comment: @Illusion You happen to know that `promise1` and `promise2` have values immediately, but Promises are meant for asynchronous behavior: Javascript won't be able to work on the results of `promise1` and `promise2` until after you've left the `try` block. The only way to make `try`/`catch` make sense here is to use `await` within an `async` function, which as Roamer-1888 points out, might be very confusing because it mixes two syntactic styles that can express the same thing.